# Reverse char array with pointer in C

Tags: c

I want to reverse a char array using pointers, but all I get when I `printf` the pointer is `null`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it. So how can I reverse the string in a similar way?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char *cstr);

int main()
{
    char a[100];
    char *p = a;
    printf("geef een string ");     // ask user to write a word
    scanf("%s", &a);

    reverse(p);

    printf("%s", *p);
}


void reverse(char *p)
{
    int i = 0;
    char temp;
    int lengte;

    for(i = 0; *(p+i) != '\0'; i++)
    {
        lengte++;                        // length of char array without the '\0'
    }

    for(i = 0; i < lengte; i++)
    {
        temp = p[i];               // something goes wrong here but I don't know  what
        p[i] = p[lengte-i];
        p[lengte-i] = tem;
    }
}
```

Something goes wrong at the

```
p[i] = p[lengte-i];
p[lengte-i] = tem;
```

part. What do I need to change it to?

Comment: Something? Almost everything. UB with `scanf()` and `printf()` (mismatching types: you have either too much or too few levels of pointers); then you reverse the string *twice.* I suggest you read a good beginner C book before trying to proceed any further.

Comment: Compilable code (albeit 2 warnings, 1 error that is clerical).  Has a question.  Goal stated.  Formatting not too bad. Accepted an answer.  Yeah, could be better but IMHO, above par for an OP's 1st post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two adjustments:

replace

```
printf("%s", *p);
```

with

```
printf("%s", p);
```

because `printf` is expecting a pointer, not a dereferenced pointer, 
and

```
for(i = 0; i < lengte; i++)
```

with

```
for(i = 0; i < lengte--; i++)
```

because your counting of the length in the loop before that one ends up with one char too many. Hence the `\0` is placed at the beginning of the string.

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
geef een string 1234
4231$
```